# How to refresh dataTable component on many machines?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, datatable, primefaces

I'm facing a problem with refreshing datatable [ primefaces module ] on many pc's. I've been using example from official website:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowSelectionSingle.jsf

code for table begins like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" var="things" value="#{tableBean.beans}" paginator="true" rows="10" selectionMode="single" ....  >
```

and for the button:

```
 <p:commandButton value="Ajax Submit" update="table" id="ajax" actionListener="#{tableBean.savePerson}" ajax="true">
```

socket code:

```
<p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/updater" />
```

code for "listener":

```
PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
pushContext.push("/updater", forBeingUpdated);
```

the code above isn't full, just the snippet. What I would like to get is something like here:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/push/counter.jsf
so, as You can see hitting the counter button make it increment on many machines. In my case I want to add rows to the table [ and this thing is done ] I can't make it working to refresh dynamically on many machines, if I add couple of records on one [pc] I have to hit refresh on another to see them. I've tried the trick from this site: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2119 but it didn't work at all. Any ideas are welcomed :). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces 4 has improved this PrimePush feature.

If you just want to update components from Push Event, try to use this snippet(taken and adapted from Primefaces 4 User Guide)

> In case you’d like to update components and/or invoke listeners in
>   your backing bean on broadcast, you can use the optional *message* ajax
>   behavior to implement the same functionality but with an extra
>   request.

And the code snippet would look something like this:

```
<p:socket channel="/updater">
    <p:ajax event="message" listener="#{tableBean.refreshTable}" update="form:table"  />
</p:socket>
```

Hope this helps!